# script to take files names add double quotes and convert to pdf

Tags: bash, sorting, pdf-generation

I am having a situation where I have some pdfs in a folder which are numbered systematically

> document fd13.pdf  document fd30.pdf  document fd47.pdf document
>   fd14.pdf  document fd31.pdf  document fd48.pdf document fd15.pdf 
>   document fd32.pdf  document fd49.pdf document fd16.pdf  document
>   fd33.pdf  document fd50.pdf

I am writing a script to convert them into a pdf

script is following

```
    #!/bin/bash
    pdftk "document fd1.pdf" "document fd2.pdf" "document fd3.pdf" 
"document fd4.pdf" "document fd5.pdf" "document fd6.pdf" 
"document fd7.pdf" "document fd8.pdf" "document fd9.pdf" "document fd10.pdf" 
"document fd11.pdf" "document fd12.pdf" "document fd12a.pdf" "document fd12b.pdf" 
"document fd12c.pdf" "document fd12d.pdf" "document fd13.pdf" "document fd14.pdf"
 "document fd15.pdf" "document fd16.pdf" "document fd17.pdf" "document fd18.pdf" 
output out.pdf
```

this does work also,

my problem is first I do an ls on the directory

```
ls ./  > script.sh
```

then I have to sort the numbers which are single digit then double ones because in such an ls output
**document fd11.pdf**
comes before **document fd1.pdf**
and also to be able to use them into my script I have to add double quotes in file name " "
this part I have to do manually.

I want to automate the addition of double quotes to file names and take the file names in a sorted order,
how do I deal these two problems?

I am on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Hm, `ls -Q -v *.pdf` gives your list, but `pdftk \`ls -Q -v *.pdf\` output.pdf` fails to pick up on the quotes...

Comment: @Wrikken: Quote characters produced by command substitution do not actually quote anything. But this is not needed, because the OP wants to create a script then execute it. So it will work if you `echo` the command to a file and run it.

Comment: Ha, learn something new every day. @n.m. : Just for sake of argument, if I _wanted_ `pdftk \`ls -Q -v *.pdf\` output.pdf` to work, what would I use instead? The required 'trailing' argument is giving me headaches :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quoting problem.

For demonstration look at the script `demo1.sh`

```
declare -a args=( "$@" ) 
echo ${#args[@]}  # count the elements of the array args
```

`bash  demo1.sh *pdf` will give you the correct number of pdf files.

If you use instead the script demo2.sh

```
declare -a args=( $@ )
echo ${#args[@]}  # count the elements of the array args
```

`bash  demo2.sh *pdf` will give you the *not* number of pdf files.
Instead it counts each file twice.

See `man bash` for the explanation:

> @      Expands  to  the  positional  parameters, starting from one.  When the expansion occurs within double quotes, each
>                 parameter expands to a separate word.  That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" ...  If the  double-quoted  expan‐
>                 sion  occurs within a word, the expansion of the first parameter is joined with the beginning part of the original
>                 word, and the expansion of the last parameter is joined with the last part of the original word.  When  there  are
>                 no positional parameters, "$@" and $@ expand to nothing (i.e., they are removed).

The following script should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
pdftk "${@}" output out.pdf
```

And you can invoke it with:

```
ls -Q -v *.pdf |xargs script
```

Comment: I am not clear with your script demo1.sh I read man page of bash but i am not clear with difference between $@ and "$@",  specially the line  `If the double-quoted expan‐ sion occurs within a word, the expansion of the first parameter is joined with the beginning part of the original word, and the expansion of the last parameter is joined with the last part of the original word. ` what does gets substituted in your script in line 2 echo ${#args[@]} how does it work and why did you have to declare args=("$@")

Comment: I updated the answer. I hope the difference $@ and "$@" has become now clearer